# Showing $\rho = -1 + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{1+\delta y} \ dy = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \delta^k k!$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Trying to understand the expansion in the title, i.e.
$$
\rho = -1 + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{1+\delta y} \ dy = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \delta^k k!.
$$ 
The paper claims to "expand in increasing powers of $\delta y$"; we have $0 \leq \delta \leq 1$.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Background information (can skip):
$\rho$ is the coefficient of correlation between two random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $(X, Y)$ follows a specific bivariate distribution, with dependence given through $\delta$. Above equivalence serves the purpose to proof that the limit for $\delta\rightarrow 0$ of the correlation ratio 
$$\eta^2 = \frac{\delta}{3} - \frac{1}{6}-\frac{\rho}{6\delta}$$ 
is $0$, since from $\rho = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \delta^k k!$ we have for $\delta=0$ that $\frac{\rho}{\delta} = -1$.

Comment: The integral converges; the series diverges.  They cannot be equal.

Comment: The suggested expansion is not true as convergent series as pointed out by several users. Rather, it can be understood as a much weaker statement that: For each fixed $N$, we have $$-1 + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{1+\delta y} \, dy = \sum_{k=1}^{N} (-1)^k \delta^k k! + \mathcal{O}(\delta^{N+1}) \quad \text{as} \ \delta \to 0^+.$$

Comment: Did you get this result by using integration by parts along the lines of Chappers' answer?

Comment: That is one possible option, but in this case we can exploit the following formula for a quick proof: $$ \frac{1}{1+\delta y}=\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-\delta y)^k + \frac{(-\delta y)^{N+1}}{1+\delta y}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated the first equation is simply wrong: it holds only for $\delta=0$, otherwise the right-hand side is a divergent series. The correct thing to do to examine the behaviour for small $\delta$ in these situations is to integrate by parts: we have
$$ -1+ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{1+\delta y} \, dy = \left[ \frac{-e^{-y}}{1+\delta y} \right]_0^{\infty} - \delta \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{(1+\delta y)^2} \, dy \\
= -1+1 - \delta \left( \left[ \frac{-e^{-y}}{(1+\delta y)^2} \right]_0^{\infty} - \delta \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2e^{-y}}{(1+\delta y)^3} \, dy \right) \\
= -\delta +\delta^2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2e^{-y}}{(1+\delta y)^3} \, dy $$
This last integral is finite, and for $\delta>0$, the denominator is larger than $1$, so it is bounded above by $\int_0^{\infty} 2e^{-y} \, dy = 2$, so as $\delta \downarrow 0$,
$$ \rho = -\delta + O(\delta^2), $$
which is enough to take the limit you need.

Answer (score 0):

What could be useful (I hope) is to consider (simple substitution $y=t-\frac{1}{\delta }$) 
$$I=\int \frac{e^{-y}}{1+\delta  y} dy=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta }} }{\delta }\int \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta }} }{\delta }\text{Ei}\left(-t\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta }} }{\delta }\text{Ei}\left(-y-\frac{1}{\delta }\right)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.
$$J=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{1+\delta  y} dy=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta }} }{\delta }\Gamma \left(0,\frac{1}{\delta }\right)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

Now, using the asymptotics of $\Gamma \left(0,z\right)$ when $z \to \infty$
$$J=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, k!\, \delta ^k$$ and then the result.

Comment: Should your first line not be $$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta}}}{\delta} \int_{\frac{1}{\delta}}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \ dt = - \frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta}}}{\delta} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{\delta}\right) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{\delta}}}{\delta} \Gamma\left(0, \frac{1}{\delta}\right)?$$ Just confused me a bit with that $t$ and $y$ in the argument of Ei. Can you elaborate on how I can use the asymptotics of $\Gamma(0, z)$ to end up with the result?

Comment: Or better: [...] to end up with the correct result pointed out by Chappers and Sangchul Lee.